# How does a DC to AC inverter work?

Tags: inverter

How does a DC to AC inverter work? It must re curve the DC wave. Is this done through a combination of on/off gates, capacitors, etc?

Brian Ghilliotti

Comment: go on to wikipedia, put 'dc to ac inverter' into search box. Read first hit. Voting to close.

Comment: Google "Royer Oscillator".

Answer (score 3):

The DC source is split in half by two capacitors. Some manner of switching device such as a MOSFET is then used to connect the AC outputs to the positive or negative side of the DC source.

This screenshot shows one driven by a full H bridge which I threw together in LTSpice. C1 and C2 are the capacitors which create the neutral point, and the switches are what controls the output.
[image: Schematic]

A less complicated method would have the AC neutral go to the point between the capacitors, and two switches pull the output above and below the neutral point. There are pros and cons to each topology.